# What is meant by createOrder: in JavaScript

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to create a PayPal button, but don't understand what createorder: mean in  this javascript code

```
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
```

Can you give me any reference about this?

Comment: Where did you get that code? If it didn't explain the code it's giving you, find another resource that does.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it amounts to asking for documentation for the API you have (inadvertently?) used, which I don't see as being useful for SO.

Comment: Can you provide the library you are using?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

With [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), the `createOrder` JavaScript function is called when a button is clicked.

The purpose of the function is to create a v2/checkout/orders object -- for the payer to then approve. The order object contains all details about the transaction taking place, including the amount.

After receiving approval from a payer, an order must be captured for any transaction to occur.

---

That [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide should have all the information you need to get started... but since you asked for a reference, see the [JavaScript SDK reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#createorder) for complete detail.

Comment: hello Preston PHX , I want to thank you for your answer, which was the first step for me to learn paypal integartion (client-side) and (server-side). I am a programmer, but I am new to PayPal, and I am not ashamed of small questions. Thank God, I am now proficient in modern paypal integration (client-side) and (server-side), and a little while ago I printed these variables. just a test

Comment: $email = $response->result->payer->email_address;
 $name = $response->result->purchase_units[0]->shipping->name->full_name;
 $address = $response->result->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address;
  $all = $response->result->purchase_units;
 $respond1 = $response->result->payer;
 $respond2 = $response->result->create_time;
 $respond3 = $response->result->update_time;
 $respond4 = $response->result->create_time;
 $respond5 = $response->result->create_time;
  $respond6 = $response->result->create_time;
  $respond7 = $response->result->create_time;

Comment: $respond8 = $response->result->create_time;
  $respond9 = $response->result->create_time;

  echo $orderID;
  echo"<br>";
  echo $email;
  echo"<br>";
  echo $name;
  echo"<br>";
  print_r($address);
  echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";
  print_r ($all);
  echo"<br>";
  echo "Respond1:   ";
  print_r ($respond1);
  echo"<br>";
  echo"<br>";
  echo "Respond_create_time:   ";
  print_r ($respond2);

Comment: 75C91876G9729662C
sb-nmaa27749913@personal.example.com
John Doe
stdClass Object ( [address_line_1] => 1 Main St [admin_area_2] => San Jose [admin_area_1] => CA [postal_code] => 95131 [country_code] => US )

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [reference_id] => default [amount] => stdClass Object ( [currency_code] => USD [value] => 10.04 ) [payee] => stdClass........................

Comment: Go live>>Thanks